How to transfer audio files from PC to SD card inserted into Bluetooth speaker?
I have a Bluetooth speaker that has SD card slot.
I inserted SD card.
The speaker has mini-USB port for charging.
My PC is connected via Bluetooth to the speaker.
Is there any way I can transfer audio files via Bluetooth to that SD card?
When I select an audio file in Windows explorer, chose to Send to Bluetooth, select the device, click Next, and get "Windows was unable to transfer some files".

If the speaker is not designed to allow you file level access, the only option is shut down the speaker, eject the sd-card and use it in a cheap usb-sdcard reader (looks like a thumb drive) that is connected to your PC. BTW: I would assume that your user name violates the Sensitive content policy


Is there any way I can transfer audio files via Bluetooth to that SD card?

No, there isn't.
There's no Bluetooth speaker in the market currently that also exposes its additional/optional SD card reader so you can transfer files to the inserted card.
Some may enable the mass storage feature when connected with a USB cable to a computer but most use the USB connection for power/charge only.

Understood. Thank you!
